# Image display issue Java

Tags: java

I'm currently tying to make my first game in java, i had successfully made a side scrolling game until i wanted to change the map (the background) a bit bigger. I started experiencing a strange problem with the background image.
it worked just fine with resolutions of up to and including 5250px x 5148px.
If I exceed this the image simply failed to display.

I've tried reducing the file size but images above this resolution still fail to display regardless of file size.

My game consists of three files
Frame, Dude and Board, they are as followed

**Frame.java**

```
package OurGame;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");

        frame.add(new Board());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Dude.java**

```
package OurGame;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Dude {
    int x, dx, y, dy, nx2, ny2;
    Image still;

    public Dude()
    {
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("/Users/Connor/Desktop/square.jpg");
        still = i.getImage();
        x = 250;
        y = 250;    
        nx2 = 485;
        ny2 = 485;
    }

    public void move()
    {
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
        nx2 = nx2 + dx;
        ny2 = ny2 + dy;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
    public Image getImage()
    {
        return still;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            dx = -1;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            dx = 1;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            dy = -1;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
        {
            dy = 1;
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            dx = 0;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            dy = 0;
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
        {
            dy = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

**Board.java**

```
package OurGame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Dude p;
Image img;
Timer time;

    public Board()
    {
        p = new Dude();
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        setFocusable(true);
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("/Users/Connor/Desktop/background.jpg");
        img = i.getImage();
        time = new Timer(5, this);
        time.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        p.move();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.drawImage(img, 485-p.nx2, 485-p.ny2, null);
            g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), 200, 200, null);
    }

    private class AL extends KeyAdapter
    {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            p.keyReleased(e);
        }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            p.keyPressed(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Before I read the rest - That's NOT javascript.

Comment: 1. Try using ImageIO to read the image into a BufferedImage. 2. Use the JPanel as the image observer in the draw image method; g2d.drawImage(img, 485-p.nx2, 485-p.ny2, this);